# CoreFoundation __exceptionPreprocess crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash-dumps, crashlytics

I am getting a Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

But there is no call to removeObjectAtIndex, and this happens in different view controllers. I am just looking for ideas as to where to look since in lines 3-5 the App is given control but there are no symbols.

The crash log is from fabric/crashlytics and it only occurred around ~30 days from app release but the instance or number of crashes is relevant.

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830502d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001948740e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182f3385c -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]
3  AppName                        0x00000001000875b8 
4  AppName                        0x000000010008698c 
5  AppName                        0x00000001000867c4 
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000194ec5994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000194ec5954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000194eca20c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
9  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830077f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830058a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
11 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182f312d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
12 GraphicsServices               0x000000018c7476fc GSEventRunModal + 168
13 UIKit                          0x0000000187af6fac UIApplicationMain + 1488
14 AppName                        0x000000010012e8cc 
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000194ef2a08 start + 4
```

Comment: You're going to have to add an exception breakpoint as frames 3, 4, and 5 are involved in some process that does call `removeObjectAtIndex` before an array has been initialized or has any objects added to it. It is not clear from this stack trace what the exact problem is

Comment: I just got the stack trace from crashlytics, I can't replicate the crash